# how to select and update same object in hibernate? illegally attempted to associate a proxy with two open Sessions

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

In my service layer, I am calling a dao class method which is calling

```
session().get(xyz.class, id);
```

I am returning the retrieved object back to service class. Then I am updating this object and passing the updated object to dao class update method.

```
getSession().saveOrUpdate(xyzObj);
```

But here instead of an update I am getting this exception

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: illegally attempted to associate a proxy with two open Sessions
```

Please tell me the right way to do a select an update of the same object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try closing the first session before getting another one, or use the same session for both operations. As an alternative i think: `getSession().merge(xyzObj);` should work.

Answer (score 1):

Found the problem.

I was using

```
 sessionFactory.openSession();
```

to get the session object. So multiple sessions were getting created. Replaced it with

```
 sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
```

Now its working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Place all DA operation with the same entity (or entities) into one Service (or named DAO) class, which encapsulate work with Session.